# Reset window.open specs in popup window

Tags: javascript

I use window.open() to create a window without scrollbar

```
window.open("...url...", "...blah...", "width=650, height=350, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no")
```

How do I reset this "scrollbars=no" to "yes" to enable scrollbar in the popup window?

I try to use css "overflow:scroll" but not work for me.

--

Edit

I have added width and height to the specs, and it still not work.

When I search DOM tree, I found there is "scrollbars.visable = false".
I try to change it to true directly by using Firebug, and the scrollbar is visable and works fine.

However, it is not work when I use javascript to change it.

```
<script>
window.scrollbars=true;  // this is not work
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `scrollbars=1` and specify `width` and `height`, that way the scrollbars would show when the content is larger than the specified window width and height.

```
window.open("...url...", "...blah...", "scrollbars=1,width=600,height=600")
```

Comment: Hi, my question is I want to set scrollbars to 0 initially, and change it to 1 in the popup window after some event. Is there a way to change it?